# Running Count of Each Category Over Time

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table that includes a person_ID, a date, and an indicator for whether the person succeeded at a task on the date, like so:

```
Person ID   Date         Status
0001        2018-01-01   Success
0001        2018-01-05   Failure
0001        2018-01-09   Success
0001        2018-01-10   Success
0002        2018-01-01   Success
0002        2018-01-03   Success
0003        2018-01-01   Failure
0003        2018-01-02   Failure
0003        2018-01-04   Success
```

I'd like to get a running count of the number of successes & number of failures experienced *to date* for each person on each date:

```
Person ID   Date         Running        Running
                         # Successes    # Failures
0001        2018-01-01   1              0
0001        2018-01-05   1              1
0001        2018-01-09   2              1
0001        2018-01-10   3              1
0002        2018-01-01   1              0
0002        2018-01-03   2              0
0003        2018-01-01   0              1
0003        2018-01-02   0              2
0003        2018-01-04   1              2
```

I really don't know where to begin with writing a query to do this - how might this be done using T SQL? Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a cumulative sum;

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when status = 'success' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by person_id order by date) as running_success,
       sum(case when status = 'failure' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by person_id order by date) as running_failure
from t;
```

Comment: That did the trick exactly; I was really trying to over-complicate this...Thank you!